# Change link CSS color without changing :hover color

Tags: css

Here's something I've never encountered before:

```css
/* These first two rules are in a CSS library */
a { 
  color: #1EAEDB;
}

a:hover { 
  color: #0FA0CE;
}

/* This rule is my own */
.example a:link {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/doesntexist">StackOverflow</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the color of just :link state without affecting :hover. Is this possible in CSS?

The first two rules are from a library, so I can't change them or their order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `:link` has the class before it, so [it is more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), and the hover is currently placed before the `:link`, so the color is overwritten by the `:link` color.

[Here is a neat Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/).

### With the limitations imposed

Duplicate the `:hover` and place the class before it, to increase its specificity. Make sure that you use the [LVHA order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link) (`:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:active`)

```css
a {
  color: #1EAEDB;
}
a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE;
}
.example a:link {
  color: #000;
}
.example a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/doesntexist">StackOverflow</a>
</div>
```

### The proper way - without the limitations

1. Use `.example a:hover`.
2. Place the `:hover` *after* the `:link`. Make sure that you use the [LVHA order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link) (`:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:active`) (Emphasis mine):

   > The :link CSS pseudo-class lets you select links inside elements. **This
   >   will select any link, even those already styled using selector with
   >   other link-related pseudo-classes like :hover**, :active or :visited. In
   >   order to style only non-visited links, you need to put the :link rule
   >   before the other ones, as defined by the LVHA-order: :link — :visited
   >   — :hover — :active.

### Working Example

```css
a {
  color: #1EAEDB;
}
.example a:link {
  color: #000;
}
.example a:hover {
  color: #0FA0CE;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/doesntexist">StackOverflow</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I should have specified, the first two rules are from a CSS library. I can't change them or their order.

Comment: Create your own hover and place the class before it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the answer. Still think it's strang that `.example a:link` changes `a:hover`

Comment: @nathancahill - Think of it this way: a link is *always* a link, even when hovered. The only style being overridden in your example is the text color. If you give your example a background color on hover, this would not be overridden by the link. If you place `.example a:link` and `a:hover` into the [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/) you will see that the link scores higher and so it wins regardless of placement in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide the :hover css

```
.example a:link {
  color: #000;
}
.example a:hover{
  color: #0FA0CE;
}
```

Because `.example a:link`  is more specific than `a:hover`

---

Let's see how specificity works:

```
Selector (per selector)          |Specificity    |     Specificity
----------------------------------------------------------------
inline-style                     | 1 0 0 0       |      1000
id selector                      | 0 1 0 0       |       100
class,pseudo,attribute selector  | 0 0 1 0       |        10
type selector and pseudo elements| 0 0 0 1       |         1   
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So `.example a:link` is equal to `10+1+10 = 21` and `a:hover` is equal to `1+10=11`.

So, after providing `:hover` the specificity value would be equal but last rule one would be taken by css.

Answer (score 1):

```
.example a:not(:hover) {
    color: #000;
}
```

it does the trick!

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is both the order and specificity of your hover style.  This works:

```
{
  color: #1EAEDB;
}

.example a:link {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.example a:hover {
  color: #38ce33;
}
```